# Having a CAShapeLayer as property causes leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, swift3, ios10

After noticing many leaks using Swift 3 and iOS 10 together I tried to reproduce one of the leaks.

I noticed that having a `CAShapeLayer` as a property in a subclass of another subclass of `UITableViewCell` causes a leak.

```
class BaseCell: UITableViewCell { }

class TestCell: BaseCell {
    let customLayer = CAShapeLayer()    // This causes a leak in instruments
}
```

[image: Cycle & Roots]

[image: Leaks by backtrace]

---

**Question:**
Can someone else confirm this is and more importantly, how can I fix this?

**Note:**
 - This doesn't happen in iOS 9.
 - If the `CAShapeLayer` is a property of `BaseCell` no leak will occur.
 - Same leak shows up if `CAShapeLayer` is replaced by `UIView`.